# I defined a Vue instance, but I can't find it

Tags: vue.js, npm

Here is my code. After Webpack, main.js ==> stem.js
[image]

But it didn't work. I couldn't find my app.
[image]

How can I fix it up?

Comment: you did not add vuejs script, <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

you did not add vue.js script. you can see below example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My first Vue app</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    {{ message }}
  </div>

  <script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You included the javascript file containing your code, but you need to include `Vue` itself as well. Place this in the `<head>` to try it out:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

For additional tips on how to include it with webpack and other ways, see the

[Vue installation documentation.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html)

PS: an easy way to prototype Vue apps is with [the Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/).